# Angular controller is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I've been learning Angular recently and in the process of creating a new website referenced I created with a tutorial. Following all the steps I was told, for some reason I am getting this error. And strangely, it is showing up as some sort of url. Here's the "error":

```
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/ng/areq?p0=PostCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
```

Removing all the url gibberish leaves PostCtrl not a function got undefined.

I don't understand why, I've looked all over Stack Overflow and all the common errors such as using global scope, not registering the controller, and other common errors don't seem to be the cause. Here is the controller and jade file.

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

(function() {

    var PostCtrl = function ($scope, $log, $location) {
        $scope.posts = [];

        $scope.post = function (title, content) {
            $scope.title = title;
            $scope.content = content;
            $log.info("Posting article: " + title + "\n" + content);
            $scope.posts.push([title, content]);
        };
    };

    app.controller("PostCtrl", ["$scope", "$log", PostCtrl]);

})();
```

Jade file: (ng-app="app") is inside the layout file, along with all other scripts involving angular.

```
extends partials/layout

block scripts
    script(src="app/controllers/PostCtrl.js")

block content
    .body(ng-controller="PostCtrl")
        .row
            .col-xs-12
                form(class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="post(title, content)")
                    .form-group
                        label(for="inputTitle" class="col-sm-2 control-label") Title
                        .col-sm-10
                            input(type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTitle" placeholder="Title" ng-model="title")
                    .form-group
                        label(for="inputContent" class="col-sm-2 control-label") Content
                        .col-sm-10
                            textarea(class="form-control" id="inputContent" placeholder="Content" ng-model="content")
                    .form-group
                        .col-sm-offset-2.col-sm-10
                            button(type="submit" class="btn btn-default") Post

        hr

        .row
            .col-xs-12
```

Comment: You forgot one dependency in the creation of the angular controller `app.controller("PostCtrl", ["$scope", "$log", PostCtrl]);` => `"$location"` is missing.

Comment: Interesting, so is $location a default dependency? I must've forgot but don't recall using it right away.

Comment: Do you have this line `var app = angular.module("app", []);` it your other scripts, in `app.js`, or somewhere else?

Comment: There are no default dependencies, if your function expects it, but you don't inject it via the array of dependencies, it comes back as undefined.

Comment: So what exactly is $location being used for?

Comment: @Jordan In this case, nothing. None of the dependencies do anything in the function without you asking (except `$scope`, which can be implicitly assigned to in the view). They're simply provided as external resources that you can then work with in the controller.

Comment: Be aware that by putting `var app = angular.module("app", []);` you are creating new app, if it's by design - cool. But if you have same line in your `app.js`, you have two instances of the app...

Comment: @Jordan FYI, if you navigate to the URL you get a nice page like [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=PostCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function,%20got%20undefined). Angular categorizes their errors and hosts pages documenting the error, and sometimes possible fixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@FlorianTopf saved the day. I was not including $location as a dependency. New PostCtrl controller:

```
(function() {

    var PostCtrl = function ($scope, $log, $location) {
        $scope.posts = [];

        $scope.post = function (title, content) {
            $scope.title = title;
            $scope.content = content;
            $log.info("Posting article: " + title + "\n" + content);
            $scope.posts.push([title, content]);
        };
    };

    app.controller("PostCtrl", ["$scope", "$log", "$location", PostCtrl]);

})();
```

Comment: Strange thing that it si working for me if I don't add the $location... http://plnkr.co/edit/qlHy66ENQ6j7CXPLKFlU?p=preview

Comment: Yeah I don't understand why either. I feel like I recall using a controller without the $location service.

Answer (score 0):

You are initiating twice the controller. Remove it from the html `.body(ng-controller="PostCtrl")`

Comment: Isn't that the only directive pointing to the controller? The script reference just brings the code in.

Comment: Hahahaha that made me laugh. Understandable ;)